# How Can I filter Facebook Events Using Location by FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How Can I fitler Facebook Events Using Location By FQL 
ex. I want to get all event which will be in Egypt

```
SELECT name FROM event 
WHERE strpos(lower(name), 'Egypt') >= 0
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name%0AFROM%20event%20%0AWHERE%20strpos%28lower%28name%29%2C%20%27Egypt%27%29%20%3E%3D%200

But when I try to use the above Query it returns that for me:

> Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an
>   indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked
>   from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql

Note : I hope to get the public events filtered by event name contains.

Comment: As the message says, you have to use some column that is indexable, and name isn't.

Answer (score 1):

With the changes that they have made, queries using an app access_token cannot
use the above query:

```
SELECT name,location FROM event WHERE contains('egypt')
```

The query works with session tokens (user `access_tokens`), however, with an app `access_token`
it just returns:

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
  "type": "OAuthException", 
  "code": 200
}
```

It was surprising to me since I could still use any other query else than contains on the events table with an app access_token

UPDATE:
After looking at their documentations, I found out that you can only use the app access token for very limited set of queries:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

What I finally did was I used the following to obtain a session access_token from my user as a page_manager

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&scope=manage_pages&redirect_uri={MY_REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=token
```

The above query returns your your `access_token` and you can use it to run your query successfully. What it basically does is that it appends your `access_token` to you as a hashed attributed

```
{MY_REDIRECT_URI}#access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

If you would like to parse the access token on the server, this would not work for you, since the hashed attribute is not sent with the request to your server. What you can do is to append `type=web_server` to the above request to facebook. In that case the `access_token` will be returned as a request parameter named `code`

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to use the `contains` predicate

`SELECT name,location FROM event WHERE contains('egypt')`

Which will get you some events that contain "egypt" in the text